# Tab based split on lines misses empty columns - Perl

Tags: database, linux, perl, file, split

I have a tab separated text file. I read line by line and column by column. I make few changes in each column and write the line to a new file. When I read each column using split function of perl

```
my @aLastOldElements = split(/\t/, $_);
```

I miss out on empty columns in the end. For example if file has 33 tab separated columns, out of which 10 in the end are empty. The split function creates array of size 23. I want to have all the columns. Because this way the header of file (33 columns) doesn't match the data (23 columns) and I get errors while writing the file to the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` accepts an optional third parameter for the maximum number of fields to return.  If this is present, empty trailing fields will not be discarded:

```
perl -E '@arr = split(/ /, "foo bar            ", 100); say scalar @arr'
14
```

So long as the tabs to separate the empty fields at the end of the line are present, this should always give you 33 fields in the array, even if the last 10 are empty.  (In my example, there are 14 fields returned because the string contains 13 separators, even though the specified limit was 100.)

**Edit:** In answer to the question in the first comment:

```
perl -wE '@arr = split(/\t/, "foo\tbar\t\thello\t", 100); say $_ || "(empty field)" for @arr'
foo
bar
(empty field)
hello
(empty field)
```

Comment: so what if we have empty field in between the line. For example "foo \t bar \t \t hello \t"

Comment: You shouldn't use 100 as a limit unless you actually want no more than 100 results.  If you just want an arbitrarily large limit, use `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the columns should be there, whether or not they have any data, you can just ensure the result yourself.

```
my @aLastOldElements = split(/\t/, $_);
my $short_fall       = 33 - @aLastOldElements;
if ( $short_fall > 0 ) {
    push @aLastOldElements => ( '' ) x $short_fall;
}
```